# Equivalance classes

Tags: real-analysis

So I need to prove that mulitiplication is a well defined operation on $\mathbb{Z}$. Multiplication is defined by $(a,b)(c,d)= (ac+bd, ad+ bc)$
So I need to prove that if $(a,b)$ and $(k,l)$ and $(c,d)$ and $(m,n)$ are equivalent then $(a,b)(c,d)$ and $(k,l)(m,n)$ are equivalent.

So I know that I must show that $(ac+bd,ad+bc)\sim (km+ln,kn+lm)$ by showing that $(ac+bd)+(kn+lm)=(ad+bc)+(km+ln)$

But when I do $(ac+bd)+(kn+lm)$ I dont see a way to make $(ad+bc)+(km+ln)$

Comment: It would be helpful to the people answering this if you give the definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ you are using.

Comment: What is your definition that $(a,b) \sim (k,l)?$  You need to use that.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb Z^2$?

Comment: Defined: $(a,b)$ ∼ $(c,d)$ if and only if $a+d=b+c$

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\mathbb Q$ as defined as quotient set of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ where $(a,b)$ is defined as equivalent to $(c,d)$ if and only if $ad = bc$?

Comment: "Defined: (a,b) ∼ (c,d) if and only if a+d=b+c "  Whoa!  You *really* need to explain the *entire* problem from the beginning.   This is something like step 4 in a very long exercise and we, your readers, have *not* seen steps 1 to 3 yet.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).